# Angular 4 how to 2-way bind element to list of ids given all id:name pairs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Given a list of Ids `vendorIds = [id,id,id]` as a subset of all ids

and a list of Id and names `vendors=[...{id:"", name:""}...]` that has all possible id name combinations

ngModel wants a list of vendors matching the list of vendorIds

Is it possible to two-way bind `[(ngModel)]` to `vendorIds` such that any changes directly update the id list and changes to the id list directly update the ngModel with correct mapping of `[ids]` to `[{id:name}]`

i've tried `.map(x=>x.id)` and `vendors.filter(x => vendorIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1)` to no avail

I would like to do this without extra variables to maintain.

This is meant to be a generic solution to combining 2 way binding with a filter as it binds to view and a map as it binds to controller/component.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this `vendorIds` or `vendors` based on a class? (structured by a class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 ngModel with map function on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857800/angular-4-ngmodel-with-map-function-on-model)

Comment: @PraveenM Yes, vendorids is a list of selected ids on a  custom Rule object. vendor is a list of all vendors as a custom Vendor object {id,name}

Comment: What do you mean by "any changes to vendorIds"? because its just an id list, how can it impact the vendors array?

Comment: @pixelbits its an id list that matches the ids of the vendors list just a variable amount of them. Basically its a multi select dropdown with x vendors to choose from and the vendorIds represents the selected vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You could split up ngModel into a binding and an event handler:

```
<any  [ngModel]="vendorIds" (ngModelChange)="onVendorChange($event)"></any>
```

Then handle `onVendorChange` by filtering:

```
selectedVendors: Vendor[] = []; 

onVendorChange(idList:number[]) {
    this.selectedVendors = idList.map(t=>vendors.find(x=>x.id == t));
    this.vendorIds = idList;
}
```

In the component template you could bind to selectedVendors:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let vendor of selectedVendors">
        {{ vendor.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Whenever the selected vendorIds change, it would automatically update the `selectedVendors`. Any component bound to `selectedVendors` would be updated automatically.

Comment: I tried something like this but `[ngModel]` needs to take vendors matching the list of vendorIds.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean

Comment: vendors is array of vendor [{id:name}...{id:name}] . It is a list of all the vendors.   vendorIds is list of ids that all exist as an id in one of the vendors. On the template I need to show both an id and a name but i only want to bind to the list of ids. Therefore the [ngModel] needs a list of vendor objects.